# how to get scala method name and class of that method

Tags: scala

I have a function which handle retry logic for given function. Inside that function I want to print a debug log with given function name and possibly the class name (Of course caller can pass that information) but I want to know how to get those values without call.

My retry method is below, now I get the methodName as an argument, can I just take it from fn ?

```
  def retry[T](attempts: Int, max: Int, operation: String)(fn: => T): T = {
    try {
      fn
    } catch {
      case e : Throwable => {
        if (attempts < max) {
          val retryAttempt = attempts + 1
          Thread.sleep((scala.math.pow(2, retryAttempt) * 2000).toLong)
          logger.debug(s"Retrying operation: $operation retryCount $retryAttempt")
          retry(retryAttempt, max, operation)(fn)
        } else {
          throw e
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: So sorry, wanted to edit but got distracted with some other work.. Extremely sorry.